# PowerShell tab completion issue

Tags: powershell, tab-completion

Suppose I have the following folder: `C:\[test]\x`, then, when inside of the `[test]` folder, I can't use PowerShell's tab completion at all.

I guess the reason for that is that the folder name would need to be escaped to `´[test´]` (with the ticks inverted, which causes Markdown problems here), as it the completion does when tabbing from inside `C:\`.

I don't really care about the missing tab completion when inside of `C:\` and typing `[t...`, but I would like to use the tab completion within that folder. Is there any way to fix that behaviour?

Comment: I cannot even enter that folder with `Set-Location` ... it needs the `LiteralPath` argument. Yikes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell and many its features in general do not work well with paths with special symbols, `[` and `]` symbols in the first place. We cannot fix the PowerShell core but we can fix/replace some features. TabExpansion is one of them. It's just a global function that can be replaced with an improved implementation.

Several custom TabExpansion implementations can be found here and there. I am using my own. It is host agnostic (at least its works well with Console, ISE, and my own host), it is reasonably simple and yet it provides a lot of improvements. Your particular problem is resolved, too.

The code of TabExpansion (dot-source it in or simply call it from your PowerShell profile):
http://code.google.com/p/farnet/source/browse/trunk/PowerShellFar/TabExpansion.ps1

Some of its features are covered by this test:
http://code.google.com/p/farnet/source/browse/trunk/PowerShellFar/Bench/Test/Test-TabExpansion-.ps1
(The test works only in the special environment, do not run it, just take a look at comments in the code to see what TabExpansion can do).